# How do you read a integer and a string seperatly from a single line in file and store them to variables?

Tags: java, text-files

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
1 Song one
2 Song two
3 Song three
...
```

How do I read a line by line and extract number and String separately from a single line, and let's say print them to the console with:

```
String title; // extracted from current line
int num; // extracted from current line    
System.out.println("Number: " + num + "Title: " + title);
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Have you tried something? If so, share with us the code so that we can better guide you on the problems you are facing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a large text file line by line using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I read a line by line

Use a [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and its [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method.

> How do I extract number and String separately

Use [`line.indexOf(' ')`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) then [`substring(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-int-) to get the 2 parts.

Then use [`Integer.parseInt(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) on the first part to get number.

Comment: How do I implement indexOf() if i have let's say more than 100 songs and the song title begins after the number separated only by a space?

Comment: You're using `indexOf` on a string containing only one line from the file, i.e. only one song, not 100 songs.

Comment: I know but what i meant is, it's not the same index when i have a one digit number and when you have 3 or 4 digit number...

Comment: Which is why you're calling `indexOf` first, to find the index of the space. Otherwise, why did you think I told you to call `indexOf`? What purpose would it have, if not that? I mean, you do know what it does, right? If not, which part of the documentation I linked to did you not understand?